# Python.Issues with indexing- running a sequence of elements backwards

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.4.1. The purpose of this program is to take a series of elements that the user types in and run them backwards. For example, "Hello" becomes "olleH". I've been trying to get this right for a while now and It's been completely stumping me for quite some time.

```
word=input("Type any word:")
word_l=len(word)
word2=None
for word in range(word_l):
    word2+=word[word_l]-i
print(word2)
```

Sorry if this seems like a serious noob question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard indexing problem.  There's a third optional argument when you're slicing that creates a step.  By setting that step to -1 you reverse the sequence:

```
>>> word = "hello"
>>> print(word[::-1])
olleh
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: If you are using string index or list indexes in a loop in Python to access each element -- look at the problem again 'cause there probably is a better way to do it.

You can simply add each character to the string in turn which will reverse the string:

```
word='Hello'
word2=''
for c in word:
    word2=c+word2
print(word2)
```

You can also just use `reversed`:

```
>>> ''.join(reversed('Hello'))
'olleH'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word=input("Type any word:")
word_l=len(word)
word2=''
for i in range(word_l):
    word2+=word[word_l-i-1]
print(word2)
```